# Error generating chart: Output of image computation is too large (12 bands for 1048576 pixels = 96.0 MiB > 80.0 MiB)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate area of classes in supervised classifications as a **bar chart**. the code goes as:

```js
var chart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image:ee.Image.pixelArea().multiply(1e-4).addBands(classified_image.rename('Classification')) , 
  classBand:'Classification' , 
  region: Pune, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  scale:10,
  classLabels: ['UrbanForest','Builtup','Road','Water','Barren','Grass','Agriculture']})
  
print(chart)
```

The error it produces is:

> Error generating chart: Output of image computation is too large (12 bands for 1048576 pixels = 96.0 MiB > 80.0 MiB). If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter.

It doesn't seem like the code I use allows tileScale as a parameter, is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few likely places in your workflow that could cause this error:

1. During training of the classifier
2. During prediction of the classes
3. During region reduction to create chart data

Without more code it's difficult to test and know. To narrow it down:

1. `print(your_training_feature_collection.limit(10))`
2. `Map.addLayer(your_prediction_of_classes)`

If it errors on these steps, you'll need to optimize your training and classification.

If it errors only while charting, you can try this alternative code to take advantage of the `tileScale` parameter. I mocked up the example with existing land cover data – you do the zonal stats reduction (instead of it happening behind the scenes of `ui.Chart.image.byClass`), convert to a feature collection, and then chart the feature collection.

```js
// Import a global land cover dataset and add a pixel area band.
var lc = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v200").first()
  .addBands(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Define a region of interest to bound zonal statistics calculation.
var roi = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.586, 47.187, -122.284, 47.372);

// Display the land cover image band and region of interest on the map.
Map.setCenter(-122.4361, 47.2835, 11);
Map.addLayer(lc.select('Map'));
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'ffffff'});

// Calculate zonal statistics for each pixel value group, defined by the values
// in the 0th (land cover) band of the image. Here, we calculate the sum of the
// pixel area for each land cover class.
var zonalStatsDict = lc.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted().group({
    groupField: 0,  // band index of land cover class band (0-based indexing)
    groupName: 'class',  // name given to group property in output dictionaries
  }),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  tileScale: 4  // divide job into smaller pieces with higher tileScale
});

// The result is a dictionary with a 'groups' key whose value is a list of
// dictionaries. There is a dictionary for each unique class found within
// the region of interest. Each dictionary contains the group name and
// respective zonal statistic.
print('Per-class area (m²)', zonalStatsDict.get('groups'));

// You can convert the list of dictionaries into a feature collection to take
// advantage of feature collection methods for further analyses and charting.
var zonalStatsFc = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List(zonalStatsDict.get('groups')).map(function(dict) {
    return ee.Feature(null, dict);
}));

// Here, we chart the area of each land cover type in the region of interest.
// First, construct a list of dictionaries that maps image class value to class name.
var hAxisLabels = [
  {v: 10, f: 'Tree cover'},
  {v: 20, f: 'Shrubland'},
  {v: 30, f: 'Grassland'},
  {v: 40, f: 'Cropland'},
  {v: 50, f: 'Built-up'},
  {v: 60, f: 'Bare'},
  {v: 70, f: 'Snow and ice'},
  {v: 80, f: 'Water'},
  {v: 90, f: 'Herbaceous wetland'},
  {v: 95, f: 'Mangroves'},
  {v: 100, f: 'Moss and lichen'},
];

// Second, pass the zonal statistics feature collection to the 
// ui.Chart.feature.byFeature function and provide the group name property;
// set chart options to specify a column chart with self-describing labels.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: zonalStatsFc,
  xProperty: 'class',
})
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({hAxis: {ticks: hAxisLabels}});

// Display the chart in the console.
print(chart);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/770dc82e8d04ccc9d996bc70bf712707)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version, producing the same results. This one may seem simpler. But I really like the use of 'group' and comprehensiveness and of Justin's approach.

```
var lc = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v200").first();
var class_values = ee.List(lc.get('Map_class_values')).aside(print);
var class_names = lc.get('Map_class_names').aside(print);

var lc_by_class = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v200").first()
  .eq(class_values.getInfo()).rename(class_names).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Define a region of interest to bound zonal statistics calculation.
var roi = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.586, 47.187, -122.284, 47.372);

var area = lc_by_class.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: roi,
  crs: lc.projection(), 
  crsTransform: lc.projection().getInfo().transform,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

var features = ee.List.sequence(0,class_values.length().subtract(1),1).map(function(n){
  var class_name = area.keys().get(n);
  var val = area.values().get(n);
  return ee.Feature(null).set('class',class_name).set('area size',val);
});

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: features,
  xProperty:'class'
})
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({hAxis: {position:null}});

print(chart);

// Display the land cover image band and region of interest on the map.
Map.setCenter(-122.4361, 47.2835, 11);
Map.addLayer(lc.select('Map'));
Map.addLayer(roi, {color: 'ffffff'});
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/eb90925a7e998fe0b5222f1285ef3b0a)